# Load a new page in JavaFX webview

Tags: javascript, java, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am currently working on a Java application that uses a JavaFX webview to display its UI (with HTML/CSS).

Everything is working fine but I have trouble loading a new page in the system. When I do, the communication between the Java and the new page's JavaScript seems to be broken.

Here is my code :

** Broser **

```
public class Browser extends Region {

final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

public Browser() {
    //apply the styles
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    // load the web page
    webEngine.load(some_url);

    JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");

    Bridge bridge = Bridge.getInstance();
    bridge.init(webEngine);

    jsobj.setMember("java", bridge);
    //add the web view to the scene
    getChildren().add(browser);

    }
}
```

** Bridge **

```
public class Bridge {
private static Bridge instance = null;

private WebEngine webEngine;

public Bridge () {
}

public static Bridge getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Bridge();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void init(WebEngine webEngine) {
    if(this.webEngine == null) {
        this.webEngine = webEngine;
    }
}

public void btnStartSessionOnClick(String sessionName, String speakerNickname) {
    // Load the new page
    webEngine.load(some_other_url);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "broken communication" ?

Comment: @fxm well whenever I try to trigger a function from the JavaScript to the Java or vice versa, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever the web engine loads a new page, it replaces the DOM, so there is a different `window` object. The `jsobj` you define is only set once, so when a new page is loaded it will be pointing to the wrong object. You need to reset this object every time the page loads, which you can do by observing the engine's load state.

Your design doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me: it makes more sense to me to have the `window` (`jsobj`) object as part of the `Bridge` class, rather than the application class. And since the `Browser` is not a singleton, it doesn't make sense to make the `Bridge` a singleton (what if you had multiple web views in your application, for example?).

Here's an SSCCE:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        Label output = new Label();

        Bridge bridge = new Bridge(engine);

        engine.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/First.html").toExternalForm());

        Button first = new Button("Load First");
        first.setOnAction(e -> engine.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/First.html").toExternalForm()));

        Button second = new Button("Load Second");
        second.setOnAction(e -> engine.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/Second.html").toExternalForm()));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Send");
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
            bridge.execute(result -> output.setText(result.toString()),
                    "showText", textField.getText());
            textField.setText("");
        };
        button.setOnAction(handler);
        textField.setOnAction(handler);

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, first, second, textField, button, new Label("Web page says: "), output);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView, null, null, controls, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `Bridge` class:

```
package application;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Bridge {


    private JSObject window ;

    public Bridge(WebEngine engine) {
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("application", this);
            }
        });
    }

    public void execute(Consumer<Object> callback, String function, Object... args) {
        callback.accept(window.call(function, args));
    }
}
```

And some simple test HTML files, which I have in a `resources` folder in the root of the classpath.

First.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>First</title>
<script>
    function showText(text) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
        return text;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the first page</p>
    <a href="Second.html">Go to the second page</a>
    <div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Second</title>
<script>
    function showText(text) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
        return text;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the second page</p>
    <a href="First.html">Go back to the first page</a>
    <div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```